# chrome extension check data from server in interval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on plug-in to Chrome. I would like in cycles 15 minutes to edit information.
How does it work? setInterval can maximum time of 1 second. I would like **15 minutes**.

```
var i = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:String(i)});
   i++;
}, ( 1000 ) );`
```

Answer (score 3):

> Use the chrome.alarms API to schedule code to run periodically or at a
>   specified time in the future.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of the 1 second limitation. If it doesn't do what you want, you can always count the seconds or minutes by yourself.

And make sure you are running it in a persistent background page.

```
function check(timeout, cb) {
    var c = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
        if (++c >= timeout) {
            c = 0;
            setTimeout(cb, 0);
        }
    }), 1000);
}

var i = 0;
check(15 * 60, function () {
   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:String(i)});
   i++;
});
```